# Initiating a TLS handshake using an ESP8266 with Arduino IDE

Tags: ssl, network-programming, packet, arduino-ide, esp8266

I'm trying to initiate a TLS handshake using an ESP8266 over TCP, but the server I'm sending the packet to keeps returning a TLS decode error (code 50).

The packet itself is composed and sent as follows:

```
const uint8_t packet[] = "\x16\x03\x03\x00\x2f\x01\x00\x00\x2b\x03\x03\x2b\x7e\x15\x16\x28\xae\xd2\xa6\xab\xf7\x15\x88\x09\xcf\x4f\x3c\x2b\x7e\x15\x16\x28\xae\xd2\xa6\xab\xf7\x15\x88\x09\xcf\x4f\x3c\x00\x00\x02\x00\xa0\x01\x00\x00";
client.write(packet, sizeof(packet))
```

I've heard that this error can result from an error in the packet, like having an incorrect length, but I think it's composed right. (for reference, I used the [Wikipedia Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_record) and some real TLS packets). 
I also came across [this thread](http://forum.streamsec.net/Forum/SSLTLS/TopicID531.htm) which mentions explicit and implicit TLS/SSL, but I'm not quite sure if/how it relates to my problem.

What am I doing wrong? I'm considering trying DTLS if this isn't feasible.

Answer (score 1):

TLS/SSL on esp is not very straightforward, to say the least. The implementation is lacking. Please see this [thread](http://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=5568&start=4).
HTH